# What is a word that means single-time optimism?

Tags: single-word-requests

Hoping for something catchy, not a mundane word. I'm looking for a word that means that you believe things will work out, this time. Preferably a word that you could divine the meaning of it while not knowing the roots, something that you wouldn't have to consult a dictionary every time you wanted to remember what it kinda meant.

Will also accept clever portmanteaus ;)

Comment: So you are currently optimistic?

Comment: Like the optimism you are feeling now that there's going to be such a word?

Comment: The outlook you describe makes me think of the lyrics to the theme song of the 1970's sitcom _Laverne and Shirley_. With that in mind, I'd suggest the chant that precedes the song: "schlemiel-schlimazl-hassenpfeffer-corporated".

Comment: So certain that this word exists, you must be *grasping at straws.*

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest *confidence*.

From [m-w](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/confidence):

> **confidence**
> noun
>
> 1. a feeling or belief that you can do something well or succeed at something
> 2. a feeling or belief that someone or something is good or has the
>    ability to succeed at something

The major difference from optimism is that it isn't a general worldview.

Answer (score 0):

It isnt' a single word, but there's an expression in English:

I *have a feeling in my bones* it's going to go well.

Answer (score 0):

### Hope

it's [defined as](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20hope&)

> grounds for believing that something good may happen.

and

> a feeling of **trust**

*Or perhaps you're looking for that word, trust?*

or possibly even

### Faith ( *to have faith that ...* )

It's not necessarily always attributed to religion.  You can have faith that something is going to happen; like having faith that you will pass an exam.

[defined as](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20faith)

> complete trust or confidence in someone or something.

Answer (score 0):

**Betting**

You could say that you're betting on something if you're optimistic that it will happen. Generally (not absolutely) you don't bet on a recurring situation.

Similarly, you could use **wager** or **gamble**. They both connote facing a situation that statistically is unfavorable, but might lead to success. Optimism is a large part of gambling.

Here's some info on Gambling / Betting. Wager is a synonym for bet.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambling

Answer (score 0):

A **good hunch**

- Hunch definition: an intuitive feeling or a premonition:
- Bad hunch example: He had a hunch that he would lose.